# Calling Dialog from another class

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am beginner to android, Instead of writing code repeatedly for dialog in each activity, I just created one class which contains all the methods to show the dialog, i have given small code snippet

```
public class Dialogues extends Activity implements DialogueMethods {


    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.show();
}

    //this method am calling

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, String ButtonText, boolean cancel) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(cancel) {

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton(ButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });
        }

        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Am calling

```
//dialogObj is instance of the above class

dialogObj.showAlertDialog(MyActivity.this, "Error", "Not Connected to Internet", "Exit", true);
```

When I run the code dialog is visible but button isn't, is this because of DialogInterace.onClickListener?, I just want to know is this good idea to do like this?, if it is then what's the correct way to do. please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just i want to share my way to you how i'm using.You can make class like and then call where you want.

```
public class DialogsUtil {

private Context mContext;

public DialogsUtil(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

/**
 * Return an alert dialog
 *
 * @param message  message for the alert dialog
 * @param listener listener to trigger selection methods
 */
public void openAlertDialog(Context context, String message, String positiveBtnText, String negativeBtnText,
                            final OnDialogButtonClickListener listener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
        listener.onPositiveButtonClicked();

    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
        listener.onNegativeButtonClicked();

    });
    builder.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create().show();
}

/**
 * return a dialog object
 * @return
 */
public Dialog openDialog(@LayoutRes int layoutId) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.setContentView(layoutId);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return dialog;
}
}
```

and i have created one interface for this dialog,

```
public interface OnDialogButtonClickListener {

void onPositiveButtonClicked();

void onNegativeButtonClicked();
}
```

Just implement this interface in your activity where you want to use dialog and with help of class object you can use dialog like this,

```
 mDialogsUtil.openAlertDialog(YourActivity.this, "text message", "positive button msg", "Negative button msg", this);
```

you can override these two methods in your acitivty,

```
@Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked() {

}

//user clicked cancel.Close the application
@Override
public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {

}
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to define all your dialogs in a base class , then call it

```
Class BaseActivity extends Activity{

int DIALOG_X = 1;
int DIALOG_Y = 2;
int DIALOG_Z = 3;
// More Dialog identifiers 

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
//More dialog objects if you need

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_X:
        // do the work to define the X Dialog
        break;
    case DIALOG_Y:
        // do the work to define the Y Dialog
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
}
```

Then another class extend BaseActivity and call

```
showDialog(DIALOG_X);
```